# How to queue actions from the result of an other action

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I have a redux application which is a survey with pages. In order to change pages, I have a NAVIGATION_NEXT_PAGE action. Reducers then handle the creation of the new page in the store. I have a bunch of other actions that set question answers or even navigate through pages. Within every new page displayed through NAVIGATION_NEXT_PAGE, I have a list of user-defined actions to be executed when the page is first displayed and when the questions are answered.

My issue is how to dispatch the actions recursively every time a new page is displayed, while still decoupling the action logic from the components. I don't want to dispatch actions in my PageContainer as I do not want the page to be displayed at all if an action asks to skip it.

This is my current solution:

```
const actionMiddleware = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
    // Execute post answer actions on the current page.
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.NAVIGATION_NEXT_PAGE:
            for (let postAnswerAction of store.getState().postAnswerActions);
                next(store.dispatch(actionFromPageAction(postAnswerAction)))
            break;
    }
    // Evaluate the action.
    let result = next(action);
    // Execute the preload actions of the new page.
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.NAVIGATION_NEXT_PAGE:
            for (let preLoadAction of store.getState().preLoadActions);
                next(store.dispatch(actionFromPageAction(preLoadAction)))
            break;
    }
    return result;
};
```

But it introduces strange behavior as sometimes react does not update my UI. Maybe my middleware breaks react-redux?

Am I on the right track. What is that the right way to dispatch actions from my middleware?

Comment: If you are not against checking out another library, then [redux-observable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable) does exactly this plus more with the power of rxjs  `Observables`. It essentially wraps your actions into a single `Observable` stream, and you are allowed to transform them in functions they call epics. Also you won't need to add a middleware, which as far as I understand should operate on a much more generic level.

Comment: Since I do not need async functionality, is there an alternative which would not depend on RxJS? For the sake of limiting dependencies.

Comment: Added an answer below, please read it carefully. Keeping actions in the store really doesn't seem like a good practice.

Comment: Turns out my problem was with the rendering. Dispatching actions from the middleware was not a problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cook up a homemade solution for this, but I highly wouldn't recommend this. This example below combines a bunch of function which have the ability to return new actions based on a given action and the store. (I have not tested it, but in theory it might work)

```
const actionTransformerMiddleware = (...transformers) => store => next => inAction => {
  transformers.map(transformer => transformer(inAction, store))
    .filter(output => !!output) // checking if non null undefined or empty array
    .forEach(actions =>
        // Here alternatively you could store.dispatch these, then the new actions
        // go through the same action transformers, but you won't be able
        // to return an identical action, since that would cause an endless cycle.
        (Array.isArray(actions) ? actions : [actions]).forEach(action => next(action))
    )
}

const whateverActionTransformer = (action, store) => {
  const {postAnswerActions, preLoadActions} = store.getState()
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.NAVIGATION_NEXT_PAGE:
      return (postAnswerActions || []).concat(preLoadAction || [])
  }
}

const myActionMiddleware = actionTransformerMiddleware( 
  whateverActionTransformer,
  // here more of these could come... but maybe they shouldn't?
)
```

However I see a few code smells in the example you posted (they are intact in my example as well).

Why are you storing actions in the store? Why are you not dispatching them individually? If that's not feasible, why not dispatch an action with just the payload these actions carry, let a thunk preform and combine all the results and give you a single output?

Comment: You are right, actions in the store is a code smell. Although the model of my page actions is not a redux action. I just wrote it that way to simplify the example. I need them in the store as I need somewhere to store what user-defined actions should happen in the multiple pages of the survey. I edited my sample, sorry for the confusion. Let me try your example and I will accept your answer later. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, I learned from this as well, had no idea how middlewares and `next` works ;) but I would advise to rename the stuff you store on state to something that is not called action. I can guarantee, it will be at least mildly confusing for the next dev who reads your code.

Comment: Good idea, I would if it were not already a term used in other projects of the company.